# Issue with facebook sharing

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios8, xcode6

I am making an `ios` app in which user have to just click a button and the content is automatically shared to the `timeline` without showing any dialog box.

When I use dialog method my content is shared via a dialog box.

But when I share without share dialog I get this error message.

```
message = "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action";
```

I already asker user for `publish_actions` permission.

I am using this piece of code:

```
 NSArray *permission = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"public_profile", @"user_birthday",@"publish_actions",@"email", nil];
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permission defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

        if (!error){
            // If the session was opened successfully
            if (state == FBSessionStateOpen){
                // Your code here
                NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                                               @"http://i.imgur.com/g3Qc1HN.png", @"picture",
                                               nil];

                // Make the request
                [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
                                             parameters:params
                                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                          if (!error) {
                                              UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Triffort.Com" message:@"Content Shared to Facebook" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                                              [myAlert show];
                                              NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
                                          } else {
                                              UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Triffort.Com" message:@"Content Not Shared to Facebook:: Reason:: publish_actions Permission Required" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                                              [myAlert show];

                                              // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                              // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                              NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
                                          }
                                      }];

            }
        }
    }

     ];
```

I have made my application Live. Currently i am only able to share using my develpment id account. Other acount show me error.

Will I have to submit my app to `facebook` for this action.Please Suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your use of the openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(..). Specifically, you're passing "publish_actions" to the readPermissions parameter, which explicitly states

> It is not allowed to pass publish permissions to this method.

You need to use openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions(..) instead

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSession for details

Comment: thnx ... have you any idea about how i can schedule facebook posts in ios

Comment: @Dalvik schedule the post to occur at a specific time, such as klout or commun.it ? I don't think you can do that natively within the facebook toolkit, you'd have to get permission to post at will to the user's timeline and then handle the timing and communications to facebook on your own server. But that's well beyond the scope of your original question here.

Comment: Please edit the original post to show the new code - don't forget you need to add a defaultAudience parameter with the new function.

Comment: i Updated my Question with the new One